# How to validate uploaded files by FluentValidation

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, file-upload, fluentvalidation

How can I validate uploaded files using FluentValidation?

```html
      <input type="file" asp-for="Files" multiple />
```

Comment: Do you want to check validation on the server-side?

Comment: Yes For example size of file /allowed extension s ,...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

your `ViewModel` must have `public IList<IFormFile> Files { get; set; }` :

```cs
    public class CustomViewModel
    {
        public IList<IFormFile> Files { get; set; }
        ...
    }
```

you must create a validator for `IFormFile` type as below:

```cs
    public class FileValidator : AbstractValidator<IFormFile>
    {
        public FileValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.Length).NotNull().LessThanOrEqualTo(100)
                .WithMessage("File size is larger than allowed");

            RuleFor(x => x.ContentType).NotNull().Must(x => x.Equals("image/jpeg") || x.Equals("image/jpg") || x.Equals("image/png"))
                .WithMessage("File type is larger than allowed");

               ...
        }
    }
```

now you can use `FileValidator` in your `CustomValidator` like this:

```cs
    public class CustomValidator : AbstractValidator<CustomViewModel>
    {
        public CustomValidator()
        {
            RuleForEach(x => x.Files).SetValidator(new FileValidator());
        }
    }
```

Comment: What if I want to add a parameter such as MaxSize? <input type="file" asp-for="Files" multiple /> <input type="hidden" asp-for="MaxSize" value="1000" /> how to add maxsize to RuleFor(x => x.Length).NotNull().LessThanOrEqualTo(MaxSize) .WithMessage("File size is larger than allowed"); in fileValidator