# input type file required validation in fluent Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

Consider the following code snippet

```
<input type='file' required />
```

Now, instead of using the required tag above, I want to use fluent Validation to select the file.
please guide me

Update my question :

```
public class UploaderValidator : AbstractValidator<FileUploadViewModel>
{
    public UploaderValidator()
    { 
        RuleForEach(x => x.Files).SetValidator(x => new FileValidator());
    }
}
```

in File Validator :

```
public class FileValidator : AbstractValidator<IFormFile>
{
    public FileValidator()
    {
      RuleFor(x=>x.Length).NotNull().LessThanOrEqualTo(100)  
    }
```

}

For example, consider the above codes.
Accreditation will only start when a file is selected from the client and sent to the server.
But my goal is to send a message if a file is not selected.
In fact, file selection must be mandatory and this is done by fluent validation

Comment: Ok. What have you tried so far? We need more information to help you. How does controller action look like? What looks your validator right now? What model is passed to the view?

Comment: `Input type="file"` is represented by the type IFormFile. Assuming by "... to select the file" you mean to validate existence of file then you can check for its Length. [Something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59358252/how-to-validate-uploaded-files-by-fluentvalidation)

Comment: Please check my question again, I updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 RuleFor(x>=x.fileupkoad.files).NotNull.WithMessage("")
 .DependentRules(()=>{
  Validator ...
  }
```

Comment: This isn't a great quality answer. Could do with a bit more detail, describe what it's doing and how that will solve the OP problem etc